# Removing Asterisks in filenames

Tags: rename

I have a number of files which contain "*" in various areas of the filename.

`*DOCUMENT.xls`
`***OTHER DOCUMENT***.DOC`

Does anyone have a suggestion to remove all instances of `*` from the names of all files?  I looked at krename but I don't know if that's the right tool, and don't quite understand regex expressions well enough to play with this without adult supervision.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: what would you like to happen when there's already a `DOCUMENT.xls` (or any other situation where multiple files have the same de-asterisk'ed name)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have one or another implementation of a perl-based `rename` utility, sometimes also called `perl-rename`, `prename` or `file-rename` depending on your system, you can do:

```
$ rename -n 's/\*//g' ./*'*'*
./*DOCUMENT.xls -> ./DOCUMENT.xls
./***OTHER DOCUMENT***.DOC -> ./OTHER DOCUMENT.DOC
```

That will delete all `*` characters from the name of all non-hidden files and directories in the current directory whose name contains at least one `*`.